# Reducing time complexity of contiguous subarray

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I was wondering how I could reduce the time complexity of this algorithm.
It calculates the length of the max subarray having elements that sum to the k integer.

a = an array of integers

k = max integer

ex: a = [1,2,3], k= 3

possible subarrays = [1],[1,2]

length of the max subarray = 2

```
    sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)

    def  maxLength(a, k):
        #a = [1,2,3]
        #k = 4
        current_highest = 0
        no_bigger = len(a)-1
        for i in xrange(len(a)): #0 in [0,1,2]
            current_sum = a[i]
            sub_total = 1
            for j in xrange(len(a)):
                if current_sum <= k and ((i+sub_total)<=no_bigger) and (k>=(current_sum + a[i+sub_total])):
                    current_sum += a[i+sub_total]
                    sub_total += 1
                else:
                     break
            if sub_total > current_highest:
                current_highest = sub_total

        return current_highest
```

Comment: Question formulation is bad, contains contradictions, example is not clear.

Comment: What do you mean max subarray? Maximum in length or what?

Comment: Hint: assuming the numbers can't be negative, search the partial sums for partners.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sliding window` algorithm for this.

Start at `index 0`, and calculate sum of subarray as you move forward. When sum exceeds `k`, start decrementing the initial elements till sum is again less than `k` and start summing up again.

Find below the python code:

```
def max_length(a,k):
    s = 0
    m_len = 0
    i,j=0,0
    l = len(a)
    while i<l:
        if s<=k and m_len<(j-i):
            m_len = j-i
        print i,j,s
        if s<=k and j<l:
            s+=a[j]
            j+=1
        else:
            s-=a[i]
            i+=1
    return m_len

a = [1,2,3]
k = 3
print max_length(a,k)
```

OUTPUT:

```
2
```